# Flight from Nassau to Newark via Miami

Tags: transit, new-york-city, miami

I'm hoping to book a flight with American Airlines from Nassau to Newark. The flight transits in Miami. I checked Nassau International has a pre-clearance procedure before I fly.

I understand that I don't have to go through immigration again in Miami. What about luggage? Will American Airlines check it all the way to New York so that I don't have to take the luggage and check it back in Miami? I have two hours transit time.

I'm not a US resident or citizen.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you go through US preclearance in Nassau, and fly on a single booking, then your luggage will be transferred to your connecting flight for you in Miami.